# Manually break lines like auto-breaking in lstlisting

Tags: spacing, listings, line-breaking

I would like to decide where the long line should break, but with actions pre-/postbreak and without advancing in line numbering.

I've tried that one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color, xcolor, listings}
\def\postbreak{\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookrightarrow\space}}}
\lstset{postbreak=\postbreak,
    breaklines=true, breakatwhitespace=true,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    xleftmargin=2em,xrightmargin=1em,
    numbers=left,frame=single
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent id mattis velit, ut ultricies massa.
        In lacus libero, porttitor quis urna id.
    \end{lstlisting}
    \begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={@}{@}]
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,@\newline\postbreak@ consectetur adipiscing elit.@\newline\postbreak@ Praesent id mattis velit,@\newline\postbreak@ ut ultricies massa.
        In lacus libero, porttitor quis urna id.
    \end{lstlisting}
    \begin{lstlisting}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,       consectetur adipiscing elit.        Praesent id mattis velit,           ut ultricies massa.
        In lacus libero, porttitor quis urna id.
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

but it brokes line spacing and frames around listing.

[image: img]

The first box is what I get normally, second box is what I get, when I try to put linebreaks, and third is what I would like to get, but without placing spaces by hand in the listing (as it can broke, when some styles change)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but both answers are not exactly what I need. But OK. I saw that the problem is connected with some bug in package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on [Mike Renfro's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163159/3954), you can use the [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package to produce the frame as the original one, not including line numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, listings}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\def\postbreak{%
  \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookrightarrow\space}}}

\lstset{postbreak=\postbreak,
    breaklines=true, breakatwhitespace=true,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    xleftmargin=2em,xrightmargin=1em,
    numbers=left
}

\mdfdefinestyle{myframe}
{
hidealllines=true,
singleextra={
  \draw 
    ([xshift=16pt]O|-P) -- 
    ([xshift=16pt]O) --
    (P|-O) --
    (P) -- cycle;
},
firstextra={
  \draw 
    ([xshift=16pt]O) --
    ([xshift=16pt]O|-P) -- 
    (P) --
    (P|-O);
},
secondextra={
  \draw 
    ([xshift=16pt]O|-P) -- 
    ([xshift=16pt]O) --
    (P|-O) --
    (P);
},
middleextra={
  \draw 
    ([xshift=16pt]O|-P) -- 
    ([xshift=16pt]O);
  \draw
    (P|-O) --
    (P);
},
innerleftmargin=0pt,
innerrightmargin=3pt,
innertopmargin=0pt,
innerbottommargin=0pt,
rightmargin=7pt,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=myframe]{lstlisting}

\begin{document}

    \begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={@}{@}]
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,@\newline\postbreak@ consectetur adipiscing elit.@\newline\postbreak@ Praesent id mattis velit,@\newline\postbreak@ ut ultricies massa.
        In lacus libero, porttitor quis urna id.
    \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Seems like I want. Now I saw, that the problem is not with my latex code, but with "frame=single" or "frame=lines". Why it is not working properly? Why it changes the height of lines?

Answer (score 4):

Working from [Formatting source listings with listings & framed packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1698493/943299), if you don't mind the frame going around the line numbers, you can use the [`framed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/framed) package and keep your frames and linebreaks intact.

```
\usepackage{framed}
```

...

```
\begin{framed}
    \begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={@}{@}]
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,@\newline\postbreak@ consectetur adipiscing elit.@\newline\postbreak@ Praesent id mattis velit,@\newline\postbreak@ ut ultricies massa.
        In lacus libero, porttitor quis urna id.
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{framed}
```

[image]